# Why does Yesod install from an exclusive Stackage snapshot fail?

Tags: haskell, docker, yesod

I'm trying to learn [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com) but can't get off the ground because I just can't seem to get it installed. To make sure that my own system (Mac, Haskell Platform) does not affect it, I'm trying to build a [Docker](http://www.docker.com) image to play in. Here is my `Dockerfile`, and even if you know nothing about Docker, it should be simple to see what I'm doing:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV HOME /root
ENV PATH /root/.cabal/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y ghc ghc-haddock zlib1g-dev curl && \
  cd /tmp && \
  curl http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install-1.20.0.3/cabal-install-1.20.0.3.tar.gz | tar xzf - && \
  cd cabal-install-1.20.0.3 && \
  sh ./bootstrap.sh && \
  cabal update && \
  sed -i "s%^remote-repo: .*%remote-repo: stackage:http://www.stackage.org/stackage/46bb2d7487546939e22612e7d757f1df5a5163e9%" /root/.cabal/config && \
  cabal update
RUN cabal install alex happy yesod-bin
```

So to summarize, I take a barebones Ubuntu, install ghc, haddock, zlib headers and curl, just enough to download and install `cabal-install` from source, then I do exactly that, and then as per the Stackage instructions, replace the existing remote-repo line in the Cabal config with the Stackage snapshot.

Everything seems to work up to that point, but yesod-bin cannot be installed:

```
root@35bacb9e52e1:~# cabal install yesod-bin
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: yesod-bin-1.2.12.4 (user goal)
trying: streaming-commons-0.1.4.2 (dependency of yesod-bin-1.2.12.4)
trying: unix-2.6.0.1/installed-f12... (dependency of
streaming-commons-0.1.4.2)
trying: yaml-0.8.9 (dependency of yesod-bin-1.2.12.4)
next goal: aeson (dependency of yaml-0.8.9)
rejecting: aeson-0.8.0.0 (conflict: unix =>
bytestring==0.10.0.2/installed-4f9..., aeson => bytestring>=0.10.4.0)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

I understand that there is a conflict there, but I don't understand how to work around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've had success using http://ghcformacosx.github.io, rather than the Haskell Platform, on OS X.

Comment: That actually looks pretty neat, or at least their site is nicer :D thanks

Comment: @Ilkka don't know if I've missed the boat but I just [wrote a blog post](https://ilikewhenit.works/blog/1) addressing this.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu's GHC is 7.6.x so it's probably that.

Comment: maybe try a update of bytestring (force reinstall if neccessary) - in this case `--force-reinstall` might help anyway - or try `cabal install yesod-bin --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals` (recommended on http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) - last time I checked it had no problem on the newest haskell-plattform (you can get it for debian-based systems here: http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html) but I think (just like persistent) you might need to restrict the versions so you don't get the newer Ver.1.4 stuff yet

Comment: @Ilkka You're exactly correct; each GHC ships with a different version of bytestring, so snapshots are not interchangeable.

Comment: Yeah, so: even though Yesod's instructions recommend against using Haskell Platform, that should work? And after installing the latest Haskell Platform, should I or should I not tell cabal to use Stackage? I'm asking because I already tried altering the Dockerfile such that it installs GHC 7.8 instead, and that lead to deps resolving but the build failing...

Comment: There should be no reason why using the GHC 7.8 snapshot should result in build failure if you're using GHC 7.8.3. __EDIT__ Unless, of course, it's because you're missing system libraries.

Comment: With GHC 7.8.3 the error was that base-unicode-symbols wouldn't install: `/tmp/pkgConf-base-unicode-symbols-0.2.215717.4: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)`. But anyhow, after I used the Generic Linux version of Haskell Platform [I got the thing working](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ilkka/yesod-stackage/).

Comment: note: if cabal-install says "invalid byte sequence" then it's locale-related, see https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1883